# Updating a specified row on a table with information from another table using a trigger and function on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a database for a petshop for class that contains the table `Animals` with IDs and the dates of the last consult requisition for each animal, amongst other irrelevant columns and the table `Requisition` which contains the animals' IDs and requisition dates.

And I need to create a trigger that will update the date of the last consult requisition for a specific animal whenever a new requisition (containing the date and ID) is inserted on the table. I'm not very good at SQL yet, but here's what I have so far:

```sql
ALTER TABLE animal
ADD lastRequestDate date;
  
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addRequestDate () 
RETURNS trigger as $$
BEGIN 
    UPDATE animal JOIN solicita ON idanimal
    SET lastRequestDate  -- here's where I got lost !!

END;
$$ language plpgsql;
  
CREATE TRIGGER updateLastRequest
AFTER INSERT ON request
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE addRequestDate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refer to the [special row variable `NEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) referring to the inserted row of the triggering table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udpate_request_date()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE animal
   SET    last_request_date = now()
   WHERE  animal_id = NEW.animal_id;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER request_after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON request
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION udpate_request_date();
```

And use proper, legal, lower-case names to make your life easier. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the function for you. Could you please check?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addRequestDate RETURNS TRIGGER as
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE
           animal
           SET    lastRequestDate = now() -- This updates the last req date to todays date.
           FROM solicita
           WHERE animal.idanimal = solicita.idanimal
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Basically we have to update animal table with todays date whenever someone adds a new row in solicita table.